# How to set a title inside subplots using matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

[image]I am creating a figure with subplots using:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(5, sharex=True, sharey=True, gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0})
```

Then I want to add a title to each subplot, but with the title *inside* the subplot. I tried using

```
for i in range(0,5):
    axs[i].set_title('title = ' + str(i), pad = -15)
```

But this approach creates the last title again in the subplot above, for reasons I don't yet understand.
I also tried appending an additional subplot, but couldn't find a convenient way to get rid of it again.

Comment: There was a bug in matplotlib that is fixed in the 3.3 release which is upcoming.  If you can use the prerelease please try that and see if this is fixed?   If not, feel free to open a bug report at github.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why this happens using `pad`. However, a workaround might be to use the argument `y=` to specify a position for the title text, along with changing the vertical alignment of the text:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(5, sharex=True, sharey=True, gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0})

for i in range(0,5):
    axs[i].set_title('title = ' + str(i), y=0.8, va="top")
```

[image]

Comment: This is pretty convenient and does what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!